# Why use Backbone JS integration with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am relatively new to Rails and backbone. I learned that some people integrate Rails and backbone in their app - but I do not clearly understand do people do that.

Rails is an excellent MVC framework - with twitter Bootstrap & html 5 boilerplate, it can be beautifully built. 
Backbone js supports more on the JS end. So for e-commerce sites, it might help bring out images on an event or show more elements as a user scroll down. Is that why?

Could someone please provide me with an example app or site or mention why rails + backbone is helpful? Thank you!

Comment: watch this: http://backbonefu.com/2012/07/using-backbone-js-with-rails-patterns-from-the-wild/

Comment: If you are using Rails to generate and serve pages from the server, then Backbone might be less useful. But if you use Rails more as a web service to serve JSON and render on the client, Backbone is more useful.